# Piping to same c program using stdin and stdout

Tags: c, unix, command-line, pipe

Let's say I have an executable called myProgram that reads from an input file and writes to an output file. A command line for this program looks like this:

```
./myProgram -o outputfile inputfile
```

The argument to the `-o` option specifies an output file name; if no such file exists then the program will create it.

What I was wondering is whether I can execute myProgram multiple times, piping the output of the one instance to the input of the next. For example,

```
./myProgram inputfile | ./myProgram -o outputfile
```

Is it possible to achieve this and if so, what would I have to implement? exec calls and forking? just simple read and write calls?

Comment: This is standard command line behavior. Check the source of any coreutils program e.g. [`cat`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src/cat.c#n655).

Answer (score 3):

Pipes work by chaining stdin and stdout of multiple programs together.

You need to modify your program to have the ability to read from stdin and write to stdout instead of to specific files.  Then you can use pipes.

Comment: So when the second myprogram is executed it should read from the stdout of the first myprogram run correct? Or is my logic wrong?

Comment: @Kevag6 Correct.  The first instance in the pipe writes to stdout, and the second instance in the pipe reads from stdin.

Comment: ... and the program does not need to know or care, @Kevag6, where its `stdin` came from.  In particular, it doesn't have to do anything special to handle the case where its stdin is connected to a pipe.

Comment: @JohnBollinger thank you for clarifying, I have one more question, in the 2nd case above which ./myprogram would get executed first? the first or the second? Thanks again

Comment: Typically, pipes are opened from right to left.  So the second would execute and be waiting on input, then the first would execute and start generating output which the second would read.  So typically both programs would be running at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is: yes, you can do this.

However, your program should then read its input from stdin and write to stdout. This means, arguments as input or output file will no longer be necessary.

```
./myProgram < inputfile > outputfile
```

or, to illustrate the chaining,

```
./myProgram < inputfile | ./myProgram > outputfile
```

A widely spread combination is to read from stdin if no input file is specified and write to stdout if no outputfile *or* outputfile "-" is passed at the command line. This provides maximum flexibility.

Having said that, if it is sensible to chain multiple instances of the same program depends of course largely on what this program *does*. For example, for a sorting program this doesn't seem to make much sense of course ;)

Answer (score 1):

There is absolutely no problem to run two instances of your program **myProgram** together as you do with command

```
./myProgram inputfile | ./myProgram -o outputfile
```

Comment: Well, it's no problem *for the shell*, but whether that has the OP's desired effect depends on the program.  I think the details of that dependency are what he's asking about.

Answer (score 0):

### You do not need to change your program.

In Unix, [everything is (represented as) a file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Everything_is_a_file), including `stdout` and `stdin`.

If your program outputs to `stdout`, then running

```bash
./myProgram inputfile | ./myProgram -o outputfile /dev/stdin
```

will work. This uses `stdin` as the input "file" to the second program.

If your program requires some output file and does not normally output to `stdout` (not sure where else it'd output to, but whatever), then you can use

```bash
./myProgram -o /dev/stdout inputfile | ./myProgram -o outputfile /dev/stdin
```

to force it to output to the `stdout` "file", and then pipe that to the next command.

### If you do want to change your program...

Make sure that it reads from `stdin` and outputs to `stdout` when no arguments are provided. Since you're programming in C, [`fgets()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4309845/950837) and [`fwrite()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62699018/how-to-use-write-or-fwrite-for-writing-data-to-terminal-stdout) should suffice in most cases (and notice both of these commands are again reading from/writing to the file descriptors for `stdin` and `stdout`).