# How to use write() or fwrite() for writing data to terminal (stdout)?

Tags: c, pipeline

I am trying to speed up my C program to spit out data faster.
Currently I am using `printf()` to give some data to the outside world. It is a continuous stream of data, therefore I am unable to use return(data).

How can I use `write()` or `fwrite()` to give the data out to the `console` instead of file?

Overall my setup consist of program written in C and its output goes to the python script, where the data is processed further. I form a pipe:

```
./program_in_c | script_in_python
```

This gives additional benefit on Raspberry Pi by using more of processor's cores.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
#include <unistd.h>

       ssize_t write(int fd, const void *buf, size_t count);
```

> `write()` writes up to count bytes from the buffer starting at buf to
> the file referred to by the file descriptor fd.

the standard output file descriptor is: 1 in linux at least!
concern using flush the stdoutput buffer as well, before calling to write system call to ensure that all previous garabge was cleaned

```
fflush(stdout); // Will now print everything in the stdout buffer
write(1, buf, count);
```

using `fwrite`:

```
size_t fwrite(const void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, FILE *stream);
```

> The function fwrite() writes nmemb items of data, each size bytes
> long, to the stream pointed to by stream, obtaining them from the
> location given by ptr.

```
fflush(stdout);
int buf[8];
fwrite(buf, sizeof(int), sizeof(buf), stdout);
```

Please refare to man pages for further reading, in the links below:

[fwrite](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fwrite.3.html)

[write](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html)

Comment: @ryyker- sure! fixing the answer.i have changed it to int cos i want to show the use of `sizeof` in this example. thanks

Comment: Calling `write` and then `fflush(stdout)` is the wrong way around. `write` always writes immediately without buffering. And stdout doesn't know about it. So you might want to write whatever's in the buffer (by calling fflush) before you call `write`, *if* you've been using stdout as well.

Comment: `write()` has nothing to do with `fflush(), I'm afraid.  Your answer is not correct at all.

Comment: @LuisColorado - thanks you  i have moved the fflush before for ensuring that all the previous garbage data in the buffer was cleaned before the write

Answer (score 3):

Well, there's little or no win in trying to overcome the already used buffering system of the `stdio.h` package.  If you try to use `fwrite()` with larger buffers, you'll probably win no more time, and use more memory than is necessary, as `stdio.h` selects the best buffer size appropiate to the filesystem where the data is to be written.

A simple program like the following will show that speed is of no concern, as stdio is already buffering output.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int
main()
{
    int c;

    while((c = getchar()) >= 0)
        putchar(c);
}
```

If you try the above and below programs:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int
main()
{
    char buffer[512];
    int n;

    while((n = read(0, buffer, sizeof buffer)) > 0)
        write(1, buffer, n);

    if (n < 0) {
        perror("read");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

You will see that there's no significative difference or, even, the first program will be faster, despite it is doing I/O on a per character basis. (as B. Kernighan & Dennis Ritchie wrote it in her first edition of "The C programming language") Most probably the first program will win.

The calls to `read()` and `write()` involve a system call each, with a buffer size decided by you.  The individual `getchar()` and `putchar()` calls don't.  They just store the received chars in a memory buffer, as you print them, whose size has been decided by the `stdio.h` library implementation, based on the filesystem, and it flushes the buffer, once it is full of data.  If you grow the buffer size in the second program, you'll see that you get better results increasing it up to a point, but after that you'll see no more increment in speed.  The number of calls made to the library is insignificant with respect to the time involved in doing the actual I/O, and selecting a very large buffer, will eat much memory from your system (and a Raspberry Pi memory is limited in this sense, to 1Gb or ram)  If you end making swap due to a so large buffer, you'll lose the battle completely.

Most filesystems have a preferred buffer size, because the kernel does write ahead (the kernel reads more than what you asked for, on sequential reads, in prevision that you'll continue reading more after you consumed the data) and this affects the optimum buffer size.  For that, the `stat(2)` system call tells you what is the optimum buffer size, and `stdio` uses that when it selects the actual buffer size.

Don't think you are going to get better (or much better) than the program listed first above.  Even if you use large enough buffers.

What is not correct (or valid) is to intermix calls that do buffering (like all the stdio package's) with basic system calls (like `read(2)` or `write(2)` ---as I've seen recommending you to use `fflush(3)` after `write(2)`, which is totally incoherent--- that do not buffer the data)  there's no earn (and probably you'll get your output incorrectly ordered, if you do part of the calls using `printf(3)` and part using `write(2)` (this happens more in pipelines like you plan to do, because the buffers are not *line oriented* ---another characteristic of buffered output in stdio---)

Finally, I recomend you to read *"The Unix programming environment"* by Dennis Ritchie and Rob Pike.  It will teach you a lot of unix, but one very good thing is that it will teach you to use perfectly the `stdio` package and the unix filesystem calls for reading and writing.  With a little of luck you'll find it in .pdf on internet.

The next program shows you the effect of buffering:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int
main()
{
    int i;
    char *sep = "";

    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        printf("%s%d", sep, i);
        sep = ", ";
        sleep(1);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

One would assume you are going to see (on the terminal) the program, writing the numbers `0` to `9`, separated by `,`  and paced on one second intervals.

But due to the buffering, what you observe is quite different, you'll see how your program waits for 10 seconds without writing anything at all on the terminal, and at the end, writes everything in one shot, including the final line end, when the program terminates, and the shell shows you the prompt again.

If you change the program to this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int
main()
{
    int i;
    char *sep = "";

    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        printf("%s%d", sep, i);
        fflush(stdout);
        sep = ", ";
        sleep(1);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

You'll see the expected output, because you have told `stdio` to flush the buffer at each loop pass.  In both programs you did 10 calls to `printf(3)`, but there was only one `write(2)` at the end to write the full buffer.  In the second version you forced `stdio` to do one such `write(2)` after each printf, and that showed the data out as the program passed through the loop.

Be careful, because another characteristic of `stdio` can be confounding you, as `printf(3)`, when you print to a terminal device, flushes the output at each `\n`, but when you run it through a pipe, it does it only when the buffer fills up completely.  This saves system calls (in FreeBSD, for example, the buffer size selected by stdio is around 32kb, large enough to force two blocks to `write(2)` and optimum (you'll not get better going above that size)

Comment: My God, I know so little! Thanks for your deep answer. Is seems my approach isn't good at all by trying to pass the data this way. Can you advise what would be better then? Please be aware it is a live data stream. Shall I try to save to file (in C progam) and simultanously read from it (python)? What if it grows too much (I need to transfer 3 bytes x 2100 SPS x 3 channels)?  Is it possible to create a pipe using a memory as medium? I don't need a complete answer here, just a hint, I will explore and try to find more knowledge/solution by myself.

Comment: Pipes are normally what is needed for this kind of data streams.  The best is to use a pipe, but don't worry about the routines you use to print the data.  Just use `stdio` to output the formatted stream and read it from the next process.  Data doesn't normally get to disk using pipes.

Answer (score 2):

The console output in C works almost the same way as a file. Once you have included `stdio.h`, you can write on the console output, named `stdout` (for "standard output"). In the end, the following statement:

```
printf("hello world!\n");
```

is the same as:

```
char str[] = "hello world\n";

fwrite(str, sizeof(char), sizeof(str) - 1, stdout);
fflush(stdout);
```

Comment: `sizeof(char)` is always `1` by definition.  (one of the few places that using the word _always_ is fairly safe :) )

Comment: @ryyker of course it is 1. But my primal goal is to make my answer understandable and substancial. x)

Comment: Not quite, your second code snippet also writes a 0 byte. And is the fflush needed?